# C++ Array out of strings

Tags: c++

I have a new class assignment where i need to make Hangman in c++. I got everything set but I can't figure out how to make an array from a string that a user has already entered. Here is what i got.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string stringToGuess;
    cout << "Hello user, please enter a word to play hangman" << endl;
    cin >> stringToGuess;
    int arrLength = stringToGuess.length();
    cout << arrLength << endl;
    char arr_To_Guess[arrLength] = {atoi(stringToGuess.c_str())};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){ 
        cout << arr_To_Guess << " ";
    }
}
```

I realize that i can accomplish this without making an array from the string but it is required to do so in the assignment.                                                      .                                                                                                         Instructions from your teacher:
We are going to do this one step at a time.
Here is the first step:
Ask the user to enter a word, save it to a string called 
stringToGuess
Then, create 2 arrays of chars called
arrToGuess, arrCurrGuess
The first array will contain all of the letters in the word the user entered, the second array will contain all of the letters the player has guess correctly so far.
If the user enter the word
programming
The values of the variables would be:
stringToGuess: "PROGRAMMING"
arrToGuess: [P, R, O, G, R, A, M, M, I, N, G]
arrCurGuess:[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _]
Your job is to make this work.
Look at this program first: https://repl.it/IZQd/0
Some things to pay attention to:
1) Make all of the letters capital.

Comment: Why do you need an array?  A string is an abstraction of an array and you can use it just like one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the length of the array is not known at compile time, you can not use an automatic array. The array has to be allocated dynamically. The simplest solution to copy a string into an array would be to use `std::vector`.

However, I suspect that your desire to create an array from a string is ill-founded. You probably don't need to do it. You could rewrite your loop like this:

```
cin >> stringToGuess;
for (char c : stringToGuess) { 
    cout << c << " ";
}
```

---

> ```
> char arr_To_Guess[arrLength]
> ```

The problem I mentioned earlier, `arrLength` is not known at compile time, so this declaration is ill-formed.

> ```
> = {atoi(stringToGuess.c_str())};
> ```

This is very strange. You attempt to initialize the first character of the new array to have the numeric value of whatever the string represents. For example:

```
string: "123"
becomes: [123, 0, 0]
```

I suspect that this is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You know, a string is an array of `char`, which means you can do this.

```
string stringToGuess;
cout << "Hello user, please enter a word to play hangman" << endl;
cin >> stringToGuess;
for(int  i = 0; i < stringToGuess.length(); i++)
{
    cout << stringToGuess[i];
}
```

Comment: `std::string` overloads the `<<` operator, so the hand written loop is not necessary.